# How to pass data between Main Widget and QObject that are in different classes

Tags: python, websocket, pyqt, pyqt5

My question is, how do I pass data between the server and the QWidget App that is running? E.g., I want to display a new label in the UI that says "Client connected" when the onNewConnection(self) function is being called in MyServer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have the following program structure for the PyQt5 application that uses the Qt Websocket Server:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QSystemTrayIcon, QStyle, QMenu, qApp, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtWebSockets, QtNetwork

import sys




class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "Title window"
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 35
        self.width = 550
        self.height = 250

    def init_ui(self):
        # Initialise UI elements like buttons, labels, ...


class MyServer(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QObject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clients = []
        self.server = QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer(parent.serverName(), parent.secureMode(), parent)
        if self.server.listen(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.LocalHost, 8765):
            print('Connected: '+self.server.serverName()+' : '+self.server.serverAddress().toString()+':'+str(self.server.serverPort()))
        else:
            print('error')
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.onNewConnection)

        print(self.server.isListening())

    def onNewConnection(self):
        print("Connected")
        #self.mySignal.emit("connected")
        self.clientConnection = self.server.nextPendingConnection()
        self.clientConnection.textMessageReceived.connect(self.processTextMessage)
        self.clientConnection.binaryMessageReceived.connect(self.processBinaryMessage)
        self.clientConnection.disconnected.connect(self.socketDisconnected)

        self.clients.append(self.clientConnection)

    def processTextMessage(self,  message):
        if (self.clientConnection):
            self.clientConnection.sendTextMessage(message)
            print(message)

    def processBinaryMessage(self,  message):
        if (self.clientConnection):
            self.clientConnection.sendBinaryMessage(message)

    def socketDisconnected(self):
        if (self.clientConnection):
            self.clients.remove(self.clientConnection)
            self.clientConnection.deleteLater()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
serverObject = QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer('My Socket', QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer.NonSecureMode)
server = MyServer(serverObject)
serverObject.closed.connect(app.quit)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant and recommended by Qt is to use signals and slots.

Also your server has an error since "clientConnection" refers to the last connected socket so if it has n "sockets" connected and the first one receives information you will send it to the last one that seems incorrect. Finally you create QWebSocketServer that you only use to store the name and the way that makes no sense, instead it is better to pass the arguments to the constructor

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebSockets, QtNetwork


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.status_label)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_status_changed(self, status):
        self.status_label.setText(status)


class MyServer(QtCore.QObject):
    statusChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, name, mode, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clients = []
        self.server = QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer(name, mode, parent)
        self.server.closed.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
        if self.server.listen(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.LocalHost, 8765):
            print(
                "Connected: {} : {} : {}".format(
                    self.server.serverName(),
                    self.server.serverAddress().toString(),
                    self.server.serverPort(),
                )
            )
        else:
            print("error: {}".format(self.server.errorString()))
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.onNewConnection)

        print(self.server.isListening())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onNewConnection(self):
        client = self.server.nextPendingConnection()
        client.identifier = QtCore.QUuid.createUuid().toString(QtCore.QUuid.Id128)
        client.textMessageReceived.connect(self.processTextMessage)
        client.binaryMessageReceived.connect(self.processBinaryMessage)
        client.disconnected.connect(self.socketDisconnected)
        self.clients.append(client)
        self.statusChanged.emit("Connected: client-{}".format(client.identifier))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def processTextMessage(self, message):
        client = self.sender()
        if isinstance(client, QtWebSockets.QWebSocket):
            client.sendTextMessage(message)
            print("Client-{}: {}".format(client.identifier, message))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QByteArray)
    def processBinaryMessage(self, message):
        client = self.sender()
        if isinstance(client, QtWebSockets.QWebSocket):
            client.sendBinaryMessage(message)
            print("Client-{}: {}".format(client.identifier, message))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def socketDisconnected(self):
        client = self.sender()
        if isinstance(client, QtWebSockets.QWebSocket):
            self.clients.remove(client)
            self.statusChanged.emit("Disconnected: client-{}".format(client.identifier))
            client.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()

    server = MyServer("My Socket", QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer.NonSecureMode)
    server.statusChanged.connect(ex.on_status_changed)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. I figured it was indeed best to use the Qt signal and slots system, but after several failed attempts to get it working, I had abandoned that method. Thanks again!